# Is this app store banking application cheating Apple?

Tags: ios-appstore

A bank uploads an free application ( [link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sib-m-passbook/id858434310?mt=8) ) on App Store. Application basically displays bank account summary with transaction history. On launch, the application displays below notice to directly debit money from customer account for the app usage. This will not give Apple 30% share of the charged amount since it is direct debit from bank account. Below is the direct debit notice. Why is this not considered a violation by Apple ?

If this is valid, can every developer,avoid 30% cut, by protecting his free application with a key to be purchased from his website ?

[image: cheating apple]

Comment: I suggest you report this to Apple if you have concerns.

Comment: This is a question that can only be answered by Apple directly. Please contact iTunes Support and let them know your concerns or questions: https://www.apple.com/in/support/itunes/contact/

Comment: I'll also suggest you report this to Apple. This can't be answered on Ask Different I'm afraid.